# Get total orders by zone

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

on admin panel opencart have a world map, and show total orders by country. i can change map by country, and need get total orders by zone, but standart get orders by country. how to change?

```html
public function getTotalOrdersByCountry() {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(o.total) AS amount, c.iso_code_2 FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "country` c ON (o.payment_country_id = c.country_id) WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' GROUP BY o.payment_country_id");

  return $query->rows;
 }
```

its code from controller

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(o.total) AS amount, z.code as iso_code_2 
                           FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o 
                           LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "zone` z ON (o.payment_zone_id = z.zone_id) 
                           WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' GROUP BY o.payment_zone_id");
```

Comment: For additional clarity, can you expand your answer a bit? - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review)